# Paypal does not list my country

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to sell online. and I tried to create a Paypal account and surprise, surprise :

Paypal doesn't support my country.

so what can I do ?

i checked out 2checkout.com and it does support my country. and 2checkout seems to mention they accept payments from Paypal account.

what do you think i should do ?

Comment: Set up a shell company in another country. Works for people in the United States wanting to avoid taxes.

Comment: Maybe find some relevant forum to ask this question.

Comment: TheTXI, thanks for your answer but i don't understand what you mean by a shell company in another country. please, explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question does not belong here, but anyway... You can wait until Paypal decides to support your country which will probably happen eventually. Otherwise you have almost no chance to accept Paypal payments without violating their rules (and if you decide not to comply, the penalties could be costly once they find out). Your best option will be to look elsewhere - setting up a merchant account in a bank that can process card payments, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use PayPal for sales. They can freeze your account with all your money for 6 months. I also never heard that people were getting their money back afterward.

Check out these countless complaints:

[paypal horror stories](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=paypal+horror+stories&btnG=Google+Search&aq=0&oq=paypal+hor&fp=Dcgaj3zEt2M)

From personal experience I can say that the couple eBay/PayPal almost certainly does not keep their customers' private data safe. Any time I relocate and update my contact details, I very soon receive spam per snail mail with the suggestion to visit some *.ar site in Andorra. Last time I relocated I gave my current address to all but eBay/PayPal and since then no spam received.

They're evil. Avoid them at any cost.

Answer (score 0):

Contact their various support/service addresses, telling them of their failure to support your country.

I guess there are corner cases, where perhaps there's some kind of political conflict regarding whether or not a country exists, but those problems don't have technical solutions so I guess they're bit off-topic, here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some countries that US banks often block (IP addresses, ACH and ATM transactions and such) citing the higher percentages of fraud originating there. If you want to use PayPal, opening an account in another country may be acceptable to them.